# integer changes to random string while trying to write it to database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

What i'm trying to do is to write different articles comments to database and give them different article ID so i can grab them later to show every article with different comments. Everything inserts to database correctly except article ID which inserts as string "dist" even though it has to be INT. I don't even have any word containing dist in my page . I'm getting 'dist' when i change my database article ID value from INT to varchar, with INT database value stays the same 0.
Here's my code.
Here i add "articleOn" to this sessions userdata.

```
$userrecipe=array("articleOn"=>$artID); //articlebeard
$this->session->set_userdata($userrecipe);//setting session
```

Here it still has his normal INT value, one number for example "4".
And later when i try to add it to database with this code:

```
public function addComment()
{
    $data=array('artID' => $this->session->userdata('articleOn'));
    $this->db->insert('comment', $data);
}
```

It adds always as zero if its INT in database or as 'dist' if its varchar.
What can i do to keep it as INT and write to database correctly.

Assigning value to artID:

```
$query=$this->db->get("article");      
foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
  $articledata=array(
  $rows->artID                             //articleABC
   );
   ?>
 <?php if($this->session->userdata("email")!=""):?>
           <a href="<?php echo site_url('site/article/'.$articledata[0]); ?    >">


public function article($artID){ //site/article
$data['artID']=$artID;
$this->load->view("articlebeard", $data);
}
```

Calling model method.

```
    public function addComment(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            header('location:articlebeard');

        }
        else
        {
    $this->load->model("model_users");
    $this->model_users->addComment();
     header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);           
    }
}
```

Comment: how you are assigning value to $artID? share that code too

Comment: in addComment you get the int value for $this->session->userdata('articleOn') ?

Comment: editted my question hope it makes it clearer. addCOmment is my model so i dont really know how to echo value from model, but as much as i tryed it's already changed to 'dist'.

Comment: instead of setting session why don't  you send article id as parameter in model method(addComment). you didnot share the code where you are calling model method? try sending artID as parameter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Edited my post again with function which calls model method. Im pretty new at this and dont really know how to send it as parameter , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you get the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i can understand from your post following is the solution:

Update your code as follow:

```
   public function addComment(){
          $this->load->library('form_validation');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'trim|required');
          if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
                 header('location:articlebeard');

          }
          else
          {
                 $this->load->model("model_users");
                 //here you have to define the article id variable
                 $artID = 1;//You can replace with your dynamic field 
                 $this->model_users->addComment($artID);
                 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);           
          }
```

}

---

and then models method should be like this

```
public function addComment($artID)
{
    $data=array('artID' => $artID);
    $this->db->insert('comment', $data);
}
```

Hope this will help, as i cannot run this code but hope this will work, if you get errors do let me know i will tell you

Comment: I think it could work but again i cannot figure out how to send parameter to addComment not model but controller. Because i need it to be not like $artID =1 , but something like $artID = $artID. And i cant get that $artID from articlebeards or from articleABC , or i am missing something ?

Comment: you can get url paramaetrs by $artId = $this->uri->segment(3, 0); as you are using <a href="<?php echo site_url('site/article/'.$articledata[0]); ?    >"> for more details: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html